# Figure spacing carrying over to next page

Tags: spacing, graphics

I'm trying to make an image align with the text it's positioned next to. I've managed to make the top align fine by using \setlength{\intextsep}{0em}%, but for some reason the bottom vertical spacing of the figure is carrying over onto the next page.

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxgSb.jpg)

I've tried using both of the following:

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0em}
\setlength{\savedbelowcaptionskip}{0em}
```

But neither seems to work for me.

So here is the code I have in the .tex file at the moment:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}%
\setlength{\intextsep}{0em}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.31\textwidth}
\centering
\smash{}{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textwidth]{Images/Introduction/amazone.jpg}}
\caption{Wounded Amazon, Ny Carlsberg Glyptotek}
\label{img:amazon}
\end{wrapfigure}

Lorem ipsum...
```

And in my .sty file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{style}[2015/04/21 Report style package]

% Graphics
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\newlength\savedintextsep % For saving the top vertical spacing for figures
\setlength{\savedintextsep}{\intextsep}
```

I can shrink the size of the image so it doesn't carry over to the following page, but then it does not align with the bottom of the text next to it... I would love it if there is a solution to removing the carry-over spacing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of the environment to specify the number of narrow lines. Here, if I counted well, it should be:

```
 \begin{wrapfigure}[21]{o}{0.31\textwidth}
```