# Wrapfigure doesn't stop

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

Title. I want the next page to start as a full line but `wrapfigure` doesn't do that. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

%symbols
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%macroscopic design
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.25em}

%microscopic desgin
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig} \restylefloat{figure}

%header
\title{A title that is quite long and has no meaning but takes up the same number of lines as the original title is this long enough}
\date{}
\author{}

%document
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget elit eu ex tincidunt viverra ac eget ante. Phasellus fringilla mi vitae metus consequat, id mattis metus ornare. Praesent malesuada, eros quis ultricies luctus, neque nunc mollis diam, eu interdum ipsum leo id urna. Phasellus cursus tincidunt libero, vel efficitur tellus pharetra quis. Maecenas in urna accumsan ex rutrum tempus. Phasellus pretium auctor posuere. Maecenas lobortis scelerisque ex at mollis. Nulla posuere magna elit, nec tristique quam iaculis eu. Aenean vitae scelerisque ex. Pellentesque blandit, augue vitae pharetra pellentesque, neque lectus maximus velit, ac hendrerit nisl orci et nibh. Etiam eu erat odio. Maecenas magna nunc, interdum quis ipsum sed, viverra egestas est. Maecenas tortor nibh, faucibus eget viverra in, fermentum in neque. Donec dui metus, sodales eget sodales et, mattis non sem. Aliquam nulla urna, cursus a nulla congue, vulputate molestie velit.

Suspendisse ex lectus, suscipit vel metus sed, molestie suscipit massa. Suspendisse non nisi sed risus lacinia efficitur a congue nunc. Sed ornare blandit iaculis. Aenean ac ornare erat. Sed est lacus, tincidunt non dapibus cursus, accumsan sed magna. Vestibulum dictum quam varius turpis tristique dapibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc posuere massa nec viverra convallis. Donec sed mi elit.Maecenas tempus ligula dolor, quis convallis mi interdum at. Etiam consectetur accumsan lorem, eu accumsan leo aliquam cursus. 

\section{Exploration}

\subsection{Background Information}

An acid, by Arrhenius’ definition, is a species that dissociates in water to form a hydrogen (or hydronium) ion and a corresponding anion.

\[ \ce{HX ->[\ce{H2O_{(l)}}] H3O^{+} + X^{-}} \]

Like acids, bases are a species that dissociates in water to form a hydroxide ion and a corresponding cation. 

\[ \ce{ZOH ->[\ce{H2O_{(l)}}] Z^{+} + OH^{-}} \]


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\chemfig{
               % 1
              -% 2
                  (
             =[:60]O% 3
                  )
    -[:300,,,1]OH% 4
}
\caption{A molecule of ethanoic acid}
\end{wrapfigure}

For this investigation, sodium hydroxide (\ce{NaOH_{(aq)}}) was used as base, along with hydrochloric acid (\ce{HCl_{(aq)}}) and ethanoic acid (\ce{CH3COOH_{(aq)}}).

When acids and bases react, they form water and a salt in an exothermic reaction. If equivalent moles of \ce{H^+} and \ce{OH^-} are added from a strong acid and a base respectively, then the reaction goes to completion and
is called neutralisation. If not, then the reaction could go into dynamic equilibrium or other ends depending on the initial situation.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can specify the number of narrow lines, in this example `\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.5\textwidth}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240466/figure-spacing-carrying-over-to-next-page/240477#240477 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287906/wrapfig-doesnt-detect-new-page.

Comment: @Marijn thank you. I haven't seen those responses. Guess I wasn't looking up the right things.